# Oracle 11g has phantom connection

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have 11g installed locally on my machine (Windows 7 64bit).

When I have disconnected all my clients from my oracle (ie no sqlplus running, no weblogic running) and then reconnect using sqlplus and I run the following script:

```
SQL> set linesize 120
SQL> SELECT            s.sid,
  2                    s.serial#,
  3                    s.username,
  4                    s.program
  5    from v$session s
  6    where username is not null;
       SID    SERIAL# USERNAME                       PROGRAM
---------- ---------- ------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------
       134      11274 FOO                         ORACLE.EXE (J000) <-- I want to remove this connection
       139      19140 MYADMIN                        sqlplus.exe       <-- My connection
       155       8941 FOO                         ORACLE.EXE (J001) <-- I want to remove this connection
SQL>
```

So I am trying to programmatically remove the connections that I have labelled in blue.

I am using the following:

```
SQL> ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION  134,11274  IMMEDIATE;
ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION  134,11274  IMMEDIATE
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00026: missing or invalid session ID
```

Is this not the correct way?  I have also tried

```
ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION  '134,11274'  IMMEDIATE;
```

When I try running the above again I will get the error message:

```
SQL> ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION  '134,11274'  IMMEDIATE;
ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION  '134,11274'  IMMEDIATE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00031: session marked for kill
```

So the connection doesn't seem to really go away.

I want to have a script that forces all 'FOO' connections to be terminated so that my build will run properly.  But my script is not working.  Do you have any ideas?  The only reliable way I can get rid of connections is to reboot.  Stopping and starting the service sometimes works - but not always - which is really weird.

Here's my PL/SQL script that I ultimately want to be able to run.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
SET LINESIZE 120
DECLARE
   theKillCmd VARCHAR2(1000);

   PROCEDURE msg(msg VARCHAR2) AS 
   BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(msg);
   END;


BEGIN

msg(' . ');
msg(' . ');
msg('Killing extraneous sessions.');
msg(' . ');
msg(' . ');

for conn in (SELECT    s.sid,
         s.serial#,
         s.username,
         s.program
  FROM   v$session s
  WHERE s.USERNAME IS NOT NULL) 
loop

  msg( '.     ' || conn.sid || ' ' || conn.serial# || ' ' ||  conn.username || ' ' || conn.program );
  IF (conn.username = 'FOO') THEN
     -- Following asks client process to kill itself
     -- theKillCmd := 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION ''' ||  conn.sid || ',' || conn.serial# || ''' IMMEDIATE ';
     -- Following tells server to kill process 
     theKillCmd := 'ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION ' ||  conn.sid || ',' || conn.serial# || ' IMMEDIATE ';
     msg( '.           ' || 'Killing connection using command : ' || theKillCmd );
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE theKillCmd ;
  ELSE
     msg('.           Ignoring .. ');
  END IF;

end loop;


END;
/

-- exit;
```

So if anyone has any ideas that would be appreciated.

I'm wondering if maybe I somehow botched the oracle installation - I don't want to yet go down the path of re-installing - would rather have a script that just kills oracle connections before I run ant oracle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That Jnnn (J000 and J001) syntax indicates it is a "Job Queue Slave Process". If you kill it, the scheduler will probably just restart it.

Look at the appropriate DBMS_JOB or DBMS_SCHEDULER API.